# How to attach my meteor application to external database?

Tags: meteor, mobile-application

How to attach my meteor app to external database?.what will be possible ways,and is it possible to use mysql as a external databse?.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an external database using the environment variables MONGO_URL and PORT at the command line when you start your Meteor application. The [deployment section](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/deploying) of the Meteor docs briefly discusses this.

You may want to check out [this page](http://meteorpedia.com/read/Environment_Variables) at Metorpedia for additional context.

Finally, currently only Mongo is officially supported, with a beta connector for Redis -- so no MySql support. See the pages on [LiveQuery](https://www.meteor.com/livequery) and [Database Drivers](https://www.meteor.com/full-stack-db-drivers) for further context.

Comment: How the client will change the data if they want some changes in the database?.How they will edit the Mongo Database?.

Comment: With the `insecure` package installed (which is by default), any changes made in a Meteor Collection will get pushed to the database. Otherwise, you would need use [collection add/deny rules](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow) and/or a [Meteor method](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods). See [this article](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/meteor-and-security/) for advice on different security patterns

Comment: Are you willing to accept my answer? Am happy to provide additional help if you are unsatisfied

Answer (score 0):

There is no mySQL support yet in Meteor. [Here's the latest from Meteor](http://info.meteor.com/blog/an-early-look-at-sql-in-meteor) on their work with Postgres.